# this[String] can't be added into a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, string, addchild

Lets say I have a MovieClip called "Box", and "String" is actually 'box' just that its not a MovieClip

The problem I'm facing now is I can't use something like circle.addChild(this[String])

I've tried tracing this[Strin]==Box and the result returns true.
And when I remove circle.addChild(this[String]), it does not add the Box into it.
BUT, when I traced is there any new object added to circle, the amount still remains the same.

Any idea what seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you, you are trying to add a `MovieClip` called (has a instance name of) *String* inside another `MovieClip` called *Box*, right?

Well, you can't give the name *String* to an object, because `String` is a class name in ActionScript 3.0
You can't name any object with any class name or protected keyword, such `if`, `for`, `class`, `Boolean`...
Those are words that ActionsScript uses globally (they are Top Level keywords).

Also, note that although you can name an object (give it an instance name of) `MovieClip`, `Sprite`, `Loader`, `Stage` and such, all theses names are used by ActionScript as class names, inside packages, that can be imported into your animation/application, and Flash will automatically import almost every one of them for you.
If you name your objects with those words you run some risks, like codes that don't work properly or don't compile at all...

As pointed by @**Bosworth99** and @**merv**, you may note, as well, the naming conventions used by ActionScript, the **UpperCamelCase** and **lowerCamelCase**.

Classes are (by convention) written with UpperCamelCase (with the first letter capitalized), which indicates that name is a class name.
Objects are, generally, written with lowerCamelCase (with lower first letter and every new composed word with upper case), indicating that word is a object name (or another keyword, which may be reserved already).

Comment: You've correctly identified the problem Hwang is having, but I think you should be more precise in differentiating between Top Level classes (eg, String) and Flash library classes (eg, MovieClip).  Technically, the latter are not restricted as long as one does not include their libraries. Also, you might want to point out the lowerCamelCase convention that is used for objects in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little odd - you say you have a MC *called* 'Box'. Are you creating this in the flash ide - or programatically? either way - you appear to be referencing Classes, and not instances of a class (an object). Try:

```
var _circle:MovieClip;
var _box:Sprite;

private function createDisplayObjects():void
{
_circle = new MovieClip();
this.addChild(_circle);

_box = new Sprite();
_circle.addChild(_box);

}
```

And - just as a generally agreed upon practice, class names are capitalized, and instance name are lowerCamelCase. I like underscores prefixing private vars, as well.

NemoStein is absolutely correct - reserved keywords will bork your code everytime...

good luck